# i want to create an selenium script to check the selected type is product image or other the website is made in angular and i can find the text

Tags: java, selenium

> ```
> <select _ngcontent-rov-c94="" id="selBItemType" formcontrolname="product_type"class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid
> ```
>
> ng-touched">
>
> Select item type
>
>
> Invoice
>
>
> Order Sheet
>
> ```
> <span _ngcontent-rov-c94="">Product Images</span>
> </option>
>
> <option _ngcontent-rov-c94="" value="Photo Shoot">
> <span _ngcontent-rov-c94="">Photo Shoot</span>
> </option>
> <option _ngcontent-rov-c94="" value="Statement">
> <span _ngcontent-rov-c94="">Statement</span>
> </option>
> </select>
> ```

Comment: This is just the HTML, Did you try any code ? Select class from Selenium ?

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Good luck 

Comment: YES@cruisepandey

Comment: @cruisepandey 
WebElement itemtype = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"selBItemType\"]"));
String placeholderVal = itemtype.getAttribute("Product Images");
String expectedVal = "Product Images"; if(placeholderVal.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedVal))                    System.out.println("The value is correct : "+placeholderVal);                       else
System.out.println("The value is not correct --- " +placeholderVal);

      this was the code but its not able to find the text and ithe website is  in angular

Comment: Can you share page URL ?

Comment: its password protected

Comment: Can you share the creds if you have any for testing ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please share us the element and screenshot =>
before clicking select => 
after clicking select option